# Finding latitude and longitudes for each point that make up an area of a neighborhood?

Tags: python, pandas, api, google-maps, geopy

I am trying to to find the latitude and longitude of every point along the boundary of a specific neighborhood. For example, I've tried using geopy - and when I input a specific neighborhood it returns one pair of coordinates. I would like the receive a list of coordinates that would outline a specified neighborhood.

To specify, I am working on getting the neighborhoods in Manhattan, NYC.

Thanks.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()

location = geolocator.geocode('Gramercy NYC')
print(location)
```

output: 
Location(Gramercy, Manhattan, Manhattan Community Board 6, New York County, NYC, New York, USA, (40.7355189, -73.9840794, 0.0))

I am getting one set of coordinates, I would like to have multiple.

Answer (score 1):

`Nominatim` class of geopy supports returning a full geometry data instead of a single point:

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")

location = geolocator.geocode('Gramercy NYC', geometry='wkt')
geometry = location.raw['geotext']
```

`geometry` would contain the following:

```
'POLYGON((-73.9901251 40.7377992,-73.9869574 40.736466,-73.9887732 40.7339641,-73.9825505 40.7313605,-73.9785138 40.7368725,-73.9847526 40.7395063,-73.9856806 40.7382199,-73.9873061 40.7389028,-73.9877245 40.7383154,-73.9897603 40.7391731,-73.9901251 40.7377992))'
```

The supported formats for geometry are `wkt`, `svg`, `kml`, and `geojson`. See [the Nominatim.geocode docs](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.18.1/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode) for more details.

You may also want to consider trying out your queries on the https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ page first, which provides a convenient web-interface which can show these geometries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that `geopy` can provide that.

What you really need are shapefiles for the geographies you are interested in. The US Census Bureau provides several of these for various types of geographies: [Cartographic Boundary Shapefiles](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html). Since your problem is specifically related to NYC, we can use a shapefile provided by [NYU](https://geo.nyu.edu/catalog/nyu-2451-34561).

Use the NYU GeoJSON file:

```
import geopandas
df = geopandas.read_file('nyu-2451-34561-geojson.json')

df[df.ntaname == 'Gramercy'].geometry
#54    (POLYGON ((-73.97849845639804 40.7367909565254...
#Name: geometry, dtype: object
```

These geometries are [Shapely MultiPolygons](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#polygons) so you can access some of the useful attributes, for instance you could estimate everything as a  rectangle instead of working with the Multipolygon:

```
df[df.ntaname == 'Gramercy'].geometry.bounds
#         minx      miny       maxx       maxy
#54 -73.989967  40.73135 -73.978052  40.743325

# Or get the full boundary:
df[df.ntaname == 'Gramercy'].geometry.boundary
#54    (LINESTRING (-73.97849845639804 40.73679095652...
#dtype: object
```

And if working in a jupyter notebook, you can get a sense of the shape:

```
df[df.ntaname == 'Gramercy'].geometry.item()
```

[image]